# rpm: define my own variable in spec file

Tags: rpm

Is there a way to declare my own variable inside of a `spec` file and refer to it as `%{my_var}` ?

I see there is `%define` and `%global` macros, but seems none of it works for my case.

Answer (score 1):

`%define` is a scoped variable and visible only in the section where it's defined, `%global` is visible in the whole SPEC file. See: https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/macros.html

example:

```
%define var1 foo
%global var2 bar
```

and use as `%{var1}` and `%{var2}`